# Why is my VS Code breakpoint in my Laravel project not working?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug, breakpoints

I am using VS Code to debug my Laravel project. I have installed the PHP Debug extension and configured PHP to debug using XDebug. Server is Apache (using Xampp). I am able to access my site using my browser, but the breakpoint I set inside my project using VS Code is never hit? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to put `xdebug_break();` into your blade file?

Comment: I place the following test code into my blade file: <?php
                    xdebug_break();
                    phpinfo();
                    ?> But then I get Call to undefined function xdebug_break() error?

Comment: Success...finally. The reason for the undefined function xdebug_break() error was I had forgotten to copy my XDebug dll file to my xamp/php/ext folder. Now when I use xdebug_break(); in VS Code the breakpoint is reached.

Answer (score 3):

I am a completely new to VS Code, Laravel & XDebug. I personally battled to set breakpoints in VS Code so I could debug my Laravel project. I am posting this to try and help any other beginners out there who battled to set breakpoints in VS Code in order to debug a Laravel project.

Visual Studio Code + Xampp + XDebug Debugging:

Install VS Code

Install Xampp

In VS Code: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Confirm PHP is installed: php -v

Install PHP Debug (Debug support for PHP with XDebug) extension in VS Code by clicking on Install

Use Xampp to get your php.ini information

---

Install XDebug:

1.1 Use XDebug Installation Wizard (https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) to generate dll needed.

1.2 Download generated dll XDebug file to: C:\xampp\php\ext

1.3 Configure PHP to use XDebug
-Go to Xampp and open php.ini file
-Add the following:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15.dll" (change this to your version of dll file)
```

1.4 Change default Xampp project directory:

-in Xampp Control Panel go to Apache config and select httpd.config

-in httpd.config go to "DocumentRoot" and change from "C:/xampp/htdocs" to a local folder where PHP projects are located.

-in httpd.config go to "DocumentRoot"'s "Directory" and change from "C:/xampp/htdocs" to same local folder where PHP projects are located.

example:
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs"

changed to:

DocumentRoot "C:/Users/..."

Directory "C:/Users/..."

---

In VS Code goto File --> Preferences --> Settings

Add the following:
php.validate.executablePath: "C:\xampp\php\php.exe"

To debug project in VS Code:

-First delete current launch.json file in .vscode

-Click on Debug --> Configure or Fix "launch.json" --> Select PHP (this will create a new launch.json file)

-In your browser, Goto localhost and open your website (project you want to debug)

-In VS Code, set a breakpoint in the file you want to debug (make sure it is in a PHP command section)

-In VS Code click on Debug --> "Listen for XDebug"

-In your browser refresh your website

-In VS Code your breakpoint should hit

Comment: Thank you for sharing the steps. I'm lost at "In VS Code, set a breakpoint in the file you want to debug". On my debug panel I see breakpoints section but I couldn't add the line I want to the breakpoints section. How exactly do you do it?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond To set a breakpoint in VS Code, click the gutter next to the line to break on.